# Github Fine-grained personal access token setup

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I have a dir on my personal computer that i was trying to upload on github.
I followed the steps:

```
git init 
git add  
git commit -m 
git remote add origin MYSSHKEY
git push -u origin master
```

I get the error
"$ git push -u origin master
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

I realized my personal access token expired and I needed to make a new one following the steps here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens

the token is made and has all the permissions but when using $ git push -u origin master , I get the same error

My goal is to be able to upload folders from my local pc to github. I am new to using git and setting up the encironemnt so please let me know if i missed anything in my description.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you get for `ssh -T git@github.com`?

Comment: Also: note that the PAT is completely independent of your SSH keys. You can use a PAT without SSH, and you can use SSH with an expired PAT.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to update your access token locally?

What I mean by that is, have you actually told your local git that you want to use the new token?

If not, I would recommend that you tried this:

```
git remote set-url origin https://username:token@github.com/username/repository.git
```

In case you have also cached your old credentials anywhere, you should update or remove that.

Finally, when you run git push and get prompted for your username and password, enter your username and use your new access token as a password.

Hope this helps! If you have more questions or this didn't solve the problem, feel free to comment this answer.